# Extraneous Keyboard Shortcut for ctrl + '^' in Mathematica 8

Tags: keyboard, customization

I would like to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> to enter a superscript. I have tried to type this two different ways, and each time i have gotten an undesirable result. According to the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, the binding is correct:

```
Item[KeyEvent["^", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"]
```

I am running Mathematica 8 on Windows Vista, and I currently have two keymaps installed--The standard QWERTY and a Progammer Dvorak--using Windows IME. My first attempt to type it is in standard QWERTY, I type the key sequence <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>. This sequence results in a dialog box as if I had entered the menu command `File -> Revert...`. On my Programmer Dvorak, I type the key sequence <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>. This sequence results in the dialog box as if I had entered the menu command `Edit -> Preferences...`. In both cases, the key sequences that I am referring to are the physical keys that I press, not the character produced, because in both cases, I type a '^' character.

I am very confused, because neither of these dialog boxes seem to have an keyboard shortcuts assigned, so I do not understand why I am reaching them. I have also looked in `MenuSetup.tr`, but I did not see anything noteworthy. What is happening, and is there a way to correct this behavior?

Comment: Notably ctrl-6 or ctrl-^ does not actually yield `Superscript` , but `Power`  (perhaps this is a version issue? ).  Of course `Power` is more useful, but I came upon this pondering how to actually get `Superscript` by keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the section of the manual about [entering two dimensional input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html) you can find the following quote. This may help.

> On a standard English-language keyboard, the character ^ appears as the shifted version of 6. Mathematica therefore accepts Ctrl+6 as an alternative to Ctrl+^.
>   Note that if you are using something other than a standard
>   English-language keyboard, Mathematica will almost always accept
>   Ctrl+6 but may not accept Ctrl+^.

Comment: I think this clears up my confusion. I had believed that holding shift was giving me the equivalent of ctrl+'^', but it was not. I was actually pressing ctrl+shift+'6' and ctrl+shift+'@', depending on whether I was using the QWERTY or Programmer Dvorak keyboard maps.